# Installing Proxmox VE 7.4 on the host machine with Secure Boot

Tags: linux, uefi, iso, proxmox

I've done some research and I have not been able to make an EFI-bootable ISO from the Proxmox ISO freely available on their website. By this I mean that the bootable ISO provided will boot fine on a system that does not have Secure Boot enabled, I tested this case. However, when Secure Boot is enabled, then selecting the Boot Menu options at startup, then choosing the USB drive containing the same Proxmox ISO, it will not boot.

From the research I have done so far, Proxmox is still compatible with EFI, it just is not setup out-of-the-box to be run like that. The Proxmox forums did not provide a solution as of today. Someone suggested to sign the kernel included in Proxmox with an OpenSSL key and `sbsign`. I've tried that entire process, enrolling the new key, and I tried signing several files. The BIOS ran into a weird support mode with alarms, telling that the hard disk did not pass the security checks. I tried adding the /EFI/boot/bootx64.efi from another source, which did not make the BIOS run into alarms, but it ended with messages regarding unsuccessful checks of the signature on the media.

I have no idea which files on the Proxmox ISO are meant to be signed manually, nor what is the correct way to enable the ISO to boot from EFI.

Does anyone know the entire process? Many thanks

Comment: Same here. Any news?